# what is the correct way to find replace content of a file in julia?

Tags: regex, file-io, julia, pcre

I am trying to comment all the ids except the required id of a file.

content of ids.txt:

```
name="app1"
id="123-45-678-90"
#id="234-56-789-01"
#id="345-67-890-12"
#id="456-78-901-23"
#id="567-89-012-34"
#id="678-90-123-45"
```

content of write_correct_id.jl:

```
#required id
req_id = "id=\"456\-78\-901\-23\""

#read file content to array
ids_array
open("/path/to/ids.txt", "r") do ids_file
ids_array = readlines(ids_file)
end

#comment all lines starting with "id =" and un-comment the line with required id
id_pattern ="^id="
id_regex = Regex(id_pattern)

for line in ids_array
if occursin(id_regex, line)
replace (line, "id" => "#id")
elseif occursin(req_id, line)
replace(line, "#$req_id" => "req_id)
end
end

#write back the modified array to the file
open("/path/to/ids.txt", "w") do ids_file
for line in ids_array
write("$line\n")
end
end
```

The elements starting with id (ie.^id=) are not recognised.

please help me!

Comment: `replace(s::AbstractString, pat=>r)` returns a copy and does not modify `s` (in your case, `line`). You probably want to do `line = replace(line, r"^id=" => "#id=")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code that strings are immutable in Julia so `replace` does not mutate a string but creates a new one.

Here is my proposal how I would write your code (note some other small differences in my implementation e.g. `count` makes sure we only make one substitution as in general there might be multiple occurrences of the pattern in some line; also `startswith` should be in general faster than `occursin` in your use case):

```
req_id = "id=\"456-78-901-23\""
id_pattern = "id="

lines = readlines("idx.txt")

open("idx.txt", "w") do ids_file
    for line in lines
        if startswith(line, "#$req_id")
            println(ids_file, replace(line, "#$req_id" => req_id, count=1))
            # or even:
            # println(ids_file, chop(line, head=1, tail=0))
        elseif startswith(line, id_pattern)
            println(ids_file, replace(line, "id" => "#id", count=1))
            # or even:
            # println(ids_file, "#"*line)
        else
            println(ids_file, line)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! small clarification please!  Should I  use print() or println() as the latter one introduces extra new lines?

Comment: I assume that you wanted new lines after every line so I used `println`. You could alternatively do `lines = readlines("idx.txt", keep=true)` so that endline character would be kept in your string and then you can use `print`. On a second thought this is probably more pure for two reasons: a) you get endlines that follow your OS, b) you do not introduce extra newline at the end if your file did not have one.